# Linux Steam: Missing libc.so.6? But I'm not?

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to get steam to work on my Debian based Linux install, but it keeps telling me I'm missing "The following 32-bit Libraries: libc.so.6"

However, I've found it in /lib/i386-linux-gnu
If this isn't where steam is looking for it, where exactly is it looking for it? Where can I copy it into so that it has it?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but someone will land here for sure.

If you already added the 386 arch and installed steam, then just start it from the terminal and it will show you the missing packages that it needs to run. This is from my terminal log:

```
$ steam
# Failed to parse arguments: Option “--disable-factory” is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.
Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed
Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 needs to be installed
Package libc6:i386 needs to be installed
Running Steam on debian 10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6
```

I just install the missing libraries with:

```
#apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

And everything went smoothly then. libc6:i386 was already installed for me. 
**Be careful** as these packages may differ for different video cards! Do not just copy the code from above.

Some good resources here:
https://wiki.debian.org/Steam